# How to create cached service from 2TB of .TIFFs to ArcGIS Server without buying Imagery Extension?

Tags: arcgis-server, imagery, cache, license

I work for a local government enterprise GIS team in California. We are an ESRI shop and were able to piggy back on our county's grant-funded aerial imagery purchase this year. We didn't have to go through the normal procurement process and were essentially gifted a bunch of high resolution imagery for our city.
I've been having issues coming up with a least cost way to get these published on our ArcGIS Server for sharing with others.

I've got 3 different formats of imagery: TIFF, JP2 and MrSID
The JP2s look horrible so we essentially have 2 formats. Our initial plan was to use ArcGIS to Mosaic the TIFFs and then create a service to be cached upon publishing. After going through the process, we found out that we'll have to purchase the Imagery Extension to be allowed to publish this way. Imagery Extension is ridiculously expensive, so I figured I'd see if I could find alternatives.

Has anyone had success in working around the Imagery Extension to cache a large amount (2TB) of imagery? I've found examples of ways around this but nothing on this scale. ArcMap crashes if I add half the images to the map.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've already created the mosaic dataset - have you tried adding it to a map document, then publishing as a map service? Once published you'll be able to cache like any other map service. I have also wanted to avoid the Image Server Extension and have had success with this approach in 10.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to create a compact cache (tool : manage tile cache) from your mosaic dataset. After publish an empty layout with option : manually tile cache generation and publish from tile cache not dynamic data. Just copy on ArcGIS Server the cache you generated with ArcGIS Desktop where the map service cache is...